# backbone.js, views and routing

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, routes, slim

I am developing an app using slim, backbone.js and jquery mobile with a MySQL backend.

The workflow is along the lines of:

1) Search for a uni module. 
2) List matching modules.
3) Select and view a module details page.
4) List lecturers associated with the module.
5) Select and view a lecturer.

I have steps 1 through 4 complete, but cannot get the lecturer detail page to display. I think I might be passing an id into the API call wrong, or my routing is messed up.

In my index.php I have a list of API calls:

> $app = new Slim();
>
> $app->get('/modules', 'getModules');
>   $app->get('/modules/:id', 'getModule');
>   $app->get('/modules/search/:query', 'getModulesByName'); 
>   $app->get('/modules/:id/students', 'getStudents'); 
>   $app->get('/modules/:id/lecturers', 'getLecturers'); 
>   $app->get('/modules/lecturers/:id/lecturer', 'getLecturer');

The last two relate to pulling the list of lecturers associated with a module, and then pulling an individual lecturer when you tap on them, showing details.

getLecturers works, and is here for reference:

> function getLecturers($id) {
>       $sql = "select l.staffNumber, l.firstName, l.lastName, l.moduleNo1, l.moduleNo2, l.email, m.moduleNo
>               from lecturertable l, moduletable m
>               where m.moduleNo=:id AND (l.moduleNo1=:id OR l.moduleNo2=:id)";
>
> ```
> try {
>     $db = getConnection();
>     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
>     $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
>     $stmt->execute();
>     $lecturer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
>     $db = null;
>
>     if (!isset($_GET['callback'])) {
>         echo json_encode($lecturer);
>     } else {
>         echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($lecturer) . ');';
>     }
>
> } catch(PDOException $e) {
>     echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
> } }
> ```

getLecturer (single) is here:

> function getLecturer($id) {
>       $sql = "select l.staffNumber, l.firstName, l.lastName, l.moduleNo1, l.moduleNo2, l.email
>               from lecturertable l
>               where l.staffNumber=:id";
>
> ```
> try {
>     $db = getConnection();
>     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
>     $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
>     $stmt->execute();
>     $lecturer = $stmt->fetchObject();
>     $db = null;
>
>     if (!isset($_GET['callback'])) {
>         echo json_encode($lecturer);
>     } else {
>         echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($lecturer) . ');';
>     }
>
> } catch(PDOException $e) {
>     echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
> } }
> ```

Here are my routes in main.js:

> var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
>
> ```
> routes:{
>     "":"list",
>     "list":"list",
>     "modules/:id":"moduleDetails",
>     "modules/:id/students":"moduleStudents",
>     "modules/:id/lecturers":"moduleLecturers",
>     "modules/:id/lecturers/:id/lecturer":"lecturerDetails"
> },
> ```

and the matching moduleLecturers and lecturerDetails functions:

> moduleLecturers:function (id) {
>           var module = new Module({id:id});
>           module.lecturers.fetch();
>           this.changePage(new ModuleLecturersPage({model:module.lecturers}));
>       },
>
> ```
> lecturerDetails:function (id) {
>     var lecturer = new Lecturer({id:id});
>     var self = this;
>     module.lecturers.lecturer.fetch({
>         success:function (data) {
>             self.changePage(new LecturerView({model:data}));
>         }
>     });
> },
> ```

I then have Lecturers and Lecturer models, along with a Lecturers collection:

> window.Lecturers = Backbone.Model.extend({
>
> ```
> urlRoot:"../api/lecturers",
>
> initialize:function () {
>     this.lecturers = new lecturersCollection();
>     this.lecturers.url = '../api/modules/' + this.id + '/lecturers';
> }
> ```
>
> });
>
> window.lecturersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
>
> ```
> model:Lecturers,
>
> url:"../api/lecturers",
> ```
>
> });
>
> //new
>
> window.Lecturer = Backbone.Model.extend({
>
> ```
> urlRoot:"../api/lecturer",
> ```
>
> });

and a lecturer view pointing to a 'lecturer-details' html template, which is the one that isn't showing:

> window.LecturerView = Backbone.View.extend({
>
> ```
> initialize:function () {
>     this.template = _.template(tpl.get('lecturer-details'));
> },
>
> render:function (eventName) {
>     $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
>     return this;
> }
> ```
>
> });

The lecturer list item, which when tapped on should get the detail view to show, contains a link: href='#modules/<%= moduleNo %>/#lecturers/<%= staffNumber %>'

Though the URL seems to be correct in the browser (...jquerymobile/#modules/999003/#lecturers/123001) the lecturer detail page just doesn't show.

I have been breaking my head with this one for a couple of days - if anyone can spot anything out of place, I would appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use double hashtag, just fix your link:

You have:

```
href='#modules/<%= moduleNo %>/#lecturers/<%= staffNumber %>'
```

The right must be:

```
href='#modules/<%= moduleNo %>/lecturers/<%= staffNumber %>'
```